# Suppose $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and differentiable with $f(0)=0$ and $f'$ is increasing. Show that $g(x)$ is increasing.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**First Question:** Show that $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{x} < f'(x)$ for $\forall 0<x$

**My attempt:** Clearly, $f$ is satifying conditions of mean value theorem. So, apply MVT to $f$ on $[0,x]$. We get $$\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} =\frac {f(x)}{x} = f'(c)$$ for some $c \in (0,x)$.
And we know that $f'$ is increasing so for some $d$ such that $c<d$ we have $f'(c)<f'(d)$. Hence we obtain $$\frac {f(x)}{x} < f'(d) $$

My **FIRST** question is how can I move into $f'(x)$ instead of having $f'(d)$.

**Second Question:** Suppose $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and differentiable  with $f(0)=0$ and derivative of $f$ is increasing. Show that $g(x)$ is increasing.

$$
g(x):=\begin{cases}
 \frac {f(x)}{x}& \text{ if } x>0\\ 
 f'(0)& \text{ if } x= 0
\end{cases}$$

First I am really sorry that I couldn't write $g(x)$ as piecewise function.

*My attemp for second question:* I need to show that if $x_1 < x_2 $ then $g(x_1)<g(x_2)$.

If $x_1=0$ then obviously $g(0)=f'(0)$ and since $0<x_2$ then $f'(0) < f'(x_2)$ so it is increasing.

Now, I know that I have to show $\displaystyle \frac {f(x_1)}{x_1} <\frac {f(x_2)}{x_2}$

Pick $x_1 > 0$ then $g(x_1)=\displaystyle \frac {f(x_1)}{x_1} < f'(x_1) $

That is where I stuck. Could you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\,x$ be any positive real number ( $x>0$ ) .
As you proved by applying MVT to the function $f$ on $[0,x]\,,\,$ there exists $\,c\in(0,x)\,$ such that $\,\dfrac{f(x)}x=f’(c)\,.$

Moreover, since $f’$ is increasing and $\,c<x\,,\,$ we get that, $\,f’(c)<f’(x)\,.$

So we proved that $\;\dfrac{f(x)}x<f’(x)\;$ for any $\,x>0\,.$

On the other hand, you can prove that $g(x)$ is increasing by noting that, for any $\,x>0\,,$

$g’(x)=\dfrac{xf’(x)-f(x)}{x^2}>0\iff\dfrac{f(x)}x<f’(x)\,.$

---

**Addendum :**

Another way to prove that $g(x)$ is increasing on $\,[0,+\infty)\,.$

Let $\,x_1,x_2\in[0,+\infty)\,$ such that $\,x_1<x_2\,.$

If $\,x_1>0\,,\,$ by applying the MVT to the function $f$ twice, first on $[0,x_1]$ and then on $[x_1,x_2]\,,\,$ it results that

there exist $\,c\in(0,x_1)\,$ and $\,d\in(x_1,x_2)\,$ such that

$\dfrac{f(x_1)}{x_1}=f’(c)<f’(x_1)<f’(d)=\dfrac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\;\;,$

$\dfrac{f(x_1)}{x_1}<\dfrac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\;\;,$

which implies

$g(x_1)=\dfrac{f(x_1)}{x_1}<\dfrac{f(x_2)}{x_2}=g(x_2)\,.$

Analogously, we can prove that $\,g(x_1)<g(x_2)\,,\,$ also in the case that $\,x_1=0\,,\,$ by applying the MTV to the function $f$ only on the interval $[x_1,x_2]=[0,x_2]\,,\,$ that is ,

$g(x_1)=f’(0)<f’(d)=\dfrac{f(x_2)}{x_2}=g(x_2)\,.$

Comment: Excellent! It is nice to take derivative of g to find g is increasing. Btw, what do you think about can we show this also by using definition of increasing? Is it durable?

Comment: @FuatRay, read the addendum in my answer.

Comment: @FuatRay, if you multiply by $x_1(x_2\!-\!x_1)$ correctly both sides of the inequality $\dfrac{f(x_1)}{x_1}<\dfrac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$, you get that $$(x_2-x_1)f(x_1)<x_1\big(f(x_2)-f(x_1)\big)\;\;,$$ $$x_2f(x_1)-x_1f(x_1)<x_1f(x_2)-x_1f(x_1)\;\;,$$ $$x_2f(x_1)<x_1f(x_2)\;\;,$$ and by dividing both sides of the last inequality by $x_1x_2$, we get that $\;\dfrac{f(x_1)}{x_1}<\dfrac{f(x_2)}{x_2}\;.$

Comment: Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @FuatRay, you are welcome !